# How to clear picker before populating new item

Tags: people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

I've created a people picker control in my form. I want it to only allow 1 user to be entered at a time. So if there's 1 user already selected, clear that picker, then resole the added user.

On my `OnUserResolvedClientScript` I have:

```
                  (pickerId, user) => {
                        console.log("picker change event", pickerId, user);

                        // Update with last selected user id
                        let userEmail = user[0].EntityData.Email;

                        frb.d.user.get(userEmail).then(user => {
                            console.log("user", user);

                            let userId = user.data.Id;

                            // Update form component
                            let picker = pickerId.split("_")[0];

                            $(`#${picker}`).attr("value", userId);
                        });
                    }
```

I also have a clear function:

```
        clear: pickerId => {
            var picker =
                SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerId];
            var users = picker.GetAllUserInfo();

            _.map(users, u => {
                picker.DeleteProcessedUser(user);
            });

            console.log("Emptied picker ", pickerId);
        },
```

So my problem is I don't know when to clear. I can clear using the `OnValueChangedClientScript` but this is called everytime you type, which is a lot. I can't do it with the `OnUserResolvedClientScript` since it clears the item just selected.